# Swift swap array objects

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift

I'm unable to swap an array of strings on cell reorder:

```
var scatola : [String] = []

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    swap(&scatola[fromIndexPath.row], &scatola[toIndexPath.row])
}
```

this code throws:

> inout writeback to computed property 'scatola' occurs in multiple arguments to call, introducing invalid aliasing

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Show us the declaration of `scatola`.

Comment: var scatola : [String] = []

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** As of **Swift 3.2/4 (Xcode 9)** you have to use the `swapAt()` method on
the collection

```
 scatola.swapAt(fromIndexPath.row, toIndexPath.row)
```

because passing the array as two different
`inout` arguments to the same function is no longer legal,
compare [SE-0173 Add `MutableCollection.swapAt(_:_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0173-swap-indices.md)).

---

**Update:** I tested the code again with **Xcode 6.4**, and the problem
does not occur anymore. It compiles and runs as expected.

---

*(Old answer:)* I assume that `scatola` is a stored property in the view controller:

```
var scatola : [Int] = []
```

Your problem seems be related to the problem discussed in https://devforums.apple.com/thread/240425. It can already be reproduced with:

```
class MyClass {
    var array = [1, 2, 3]

    func foo() {
        swap(&array[0], &array[1])
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error: inout writeback to computed property 'array' occurs in multiple arguments to call, introducing invalid aliasing
        swap(&array[0], &array[1])
                         ^~~~~~~~
note: concurrent writeback occurred here
        swap(&array[0], &array[1])
              ^~~~~~~~
```

I haven't yet grasped the
contents of the discussion completely (too late here :), but there is one proposed
"workaround", namely to mark the property as final (so that you cannot override it
in a subclass):

```
final var scatola : [Int] = []
```

Another workaround that I found is to get a pointer on the underlying array storage:

```
scatola.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (inout ptr:UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int>) -> Void in
    swap(&ptr[fromIndexPath.row], &ptr[toIndexPath.row])
}
```

Of course, the fool-proof solution would simply be

```
let tmp = scatola[fromIndexPath.row]
scatola[fromIndexPath.row] = scatola[toIndexPath.row]
scatola[toIndexPath.row] = tmp
```

Comment: in Swift 3.2 and up, you need to write `swapAt(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively,

```
let f = fromIndexPath.row, t = toIndexPath.row
(scatola[f], scatola[t]) = (scatola[t], scatola[f])
```

Comment: Great and concise solution, +1

Comment: And it's more secure then swap, because swap crashes if the indexes are the same. Could not happen in this example but generally the indexes have to be checked before using swap. +1

Comment: This works for object arrays too. Swap doesn't work with arrays of objects, it ends up replacing both indexes with the same object

Answer (score 0):

Starting Xcode 9, you can write:

```
@objc override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, 
                  to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    scatola.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```